# Date formatting incoming RSS feed best practice

Tags: javascript, datetime, date, rss, google-feed-api

I am currently importing an RSS feed from a WordPress blog and the data that is coming in is okay for the most part although the formatting on the date is a bit more than what I need `Sun, 20 Feb 2011 07:43:06 -0800` I would like ot to display as `February 20th, 2011` I am using the Google Feed API to parse the feed.  Any and all input will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [date.js library](http://www.datejs.com/) can help you out here:

```
Date.parse( str ).toString('MMMM ddS, yyyy')
```

where `str` is the data that you get from the RSS feed.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/XZFpC/

Comment: worked like a charm, thank you!  Although I am a bit confused about how that works in jsfiddle without the date.js loaded. +1

Comment: @jnolte It is loaded `:)`. Check out the left column under "Manage Resources".

Comment: doh!  Great tool, I am just clearly not all that familiar with it. Thanks again.